# org mode repeated task up to a certain date/after x number of occurrences

Tags: org-mode

I am new to org-mode, and I am currently learning how to use the habit/TODO features. I would like to add a repeated task that will stop after a certain number of occurrences, or up to a certain date.

If I look [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html), it seems I can use :PROPERTIES: as in

```
 ** TODO Shave
    SCHEDULED: <2009-10-17 Sat .+2d/4d>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE:    habit
    :LAST_REPEAT: [2009-10-19 Mon 00:36]
    :END:
```

However, C-c C-x p does not give me LAST_REPEAT option, and I was wondering what I can do.

Answer (score 4):

The "LAST_REPEAT" property records when the habit was last done, it isn't "repeat up to this date".  AFAICT there isn't a way of specifying to repeat something N times or up until a specific date.

Answer (score 0):

When you press `TAB` at the `Property:` prompt, you get a list of possible completions, but you are not limited to them. You can always type `LAST_REPEAT` at the `Property:` prompt (and it will add it to the completion list as well).